# "Exceptional" primes greater than 2

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

In many theorems, the prime $2$ has an exceptional characteristic.  But where can other primes be exceptional?  As a couple examples:

1)  In the Fibonacci sequence $5$ is exceptional because $p=5$ allows $p|F_p$, unlike other primes where instead $p|F_{p+1}$ or $p|F_{p-1}$.

2)  Pandiagonal Latin squares have both $2$ and $3$ as exceptional primes because none exist when the order of the square is divisible by $2$ or $3$.

Comment: Every prime $q$ is coprime to $p$, with the exceptional prime $p$ being the only exception.

Comment: Every elliptic curve over a field $k$ can be written in the form
$$y^2=x^3+ax+b,$$
with $a,b\in k$, except if $\operatorname{char}k\leq3$.

Comment: Are they still "exceptional" if they're in a finite set of 8? I'm thinking specifically of $-2, -3, -7, -11, -19, -43, -67, -163$. Or how about 2, 3, 5, 11, 17, 41?

Comment: Yes.  Note my group of two with the Latin squares.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monstrous_moonshine#Origin_of_the_term

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one possible non-trivial and exceptional prime, the existence or non-existence of which is not yet proven.

It is believed, but not yet proven, that there does not exist positive integers $m$ and $n$ for which $\zeta(1+m/n)$ is a positive integer. However when it comes to prime we can prove a slightly better result i.e.

> *There exists either none or at most only one prime $p$ such that*
>   *$\zeta(1+p/n)$ is an positive integer for some natural number $n$*.

I believe there is no such prime, but if we are wrong then there will be at most one such prime, making this prime truly exceptional.